# Regex of known string + mixed varchar + known string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a hard time using regex. I've done a lot of testing with [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) but could not solve this..

I have this string: `setVersion('2.0.2.4999');`

And I want to be able to replace the version number, which is always composed of 4 numbers dot separated, but they may be of more than 1 digit each.

I would prefer to solve this in (preferably) 1 line, as I need to insert this in a gulp task.

I've tried this:

```
/setVersion\('([0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9])/
```

but it does work only if each number has only 1 digit, which is not my case.

How can I make it work so that it searches multiple times for the numbers?

Comment: `[0-9]+` would catch one or more digits. And you need to escape the dots as `\.` – otherwise they mean any arbitrary character.

Comment: Where's the comma? _4 numbers comma separated_

Comment: Sorry, dot separated, got lost in translation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match one or more of the preceding characters you can use `+` quantifier. Note that the RegEx is missing end `'` and `)` which need to be escaped.

```
/setVersion\('([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})'\)/
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dC2uN7/1)

Comment: I think you are missing a `'` at the end? Unless you don't want to replace that.

Comment: @putvande Right, added `'` and missing `)`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

You can replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. Dots (`.`) represent any character in `regex` so they are escaped.

More precise answer will be

```
\d+(?:\.\d+){3}
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\d+ #Match one or more digits
(?: #Non-capturing group
  \. #Match . literally
  \d+ #Match one or more digits
)
{3} #Repeat whatever was previously in () three times
```

Your final regex looks like

```
setVersion\('(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})'\)
```

or

```
setVersion\('(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'\)
```

Comment: please explain why (for him, i see dot's are not escaped)

Comment: @llamerr added an explanation

Comment: @ghego1 You may like using [Regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#setVersion%5C('(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7B3%7D)'%5C)) to visualize this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "+" quantifier, which will match between 1 and unlimited numbers. Also you have to escape the ".", because otherwise it will match any character.

Try this:

> `setVersion\('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF1zJ8/2)